# Table's key pointing to its own table?

Tags: sql-server, key, northwind

[class diagram http://img223.imageshack.us/img223/8558/classdiagram.png](http://img223.imageshack.us/img223/8558/classdiagram.png)

In this image,  why is the EmployeeID pointing to it's own table while the order id is not pointing to the order's table. The screenshot is a picture of the northwind database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because employees [EmployeeID] report to other Employees [ReportsTo]. An order belonging to another order hurts my brain.

Comment: Ahh damn. I see the connection when i clicked on the arrow. The key "Foreign Key Columns" has a set value "ReportsTo". I know you know this already but i'm just clarifying the answer to whoever is reading this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `EmployeeID` is probably being referred to by the `ReportTo` field.  For example, a given employee reports to another employee, using `EmployeeID` as the reference.

The `OrderID` does not point to the Order table because there are no other fields in the Order table that uses/refers to the `OrderID`.

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly referred to as a "self-join".

Answer (score 0):

Notice that an Employee could be subordinate to another one (ReportsTo) so you need the EmployeeID for that which is the PK of this table.